# How do I simulate user clicking a link in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now there's quite a lot of similar-looking questions here, but I was wondering, what should I do, if I want not to just change the `location` of the window, but trigger whatever functions may be bound to the `click` event, and only change the `href` if they are ok with it, or just redirect, if there are no listeners.

For example:

```
var a = $('.edithost');
a.click(function() {return false;});
```

Should I click the link with mouse, it never takes me to the href, so just redirecting user to `attr('href')` would change the intended behavior of the page. Besides, clicking applies not only to links, but to, say, buttons too, in which case I would have to submit the form, etc.

So I was wondering, whether it is possible to emulate clicking an element, so that all the behavior of the browser is exactly the same, as if clicked with mouse?

There can be no listeners bound to a link.

Example:

```
var a = $('<a href="google.com">google</a>');
a.click();
a.trigger('click');
```

This won't take you to Google, I want to make it do.

**Update:
`.click()` won't work. `trigger('click')` too. `preventDefault` has nothing to do with this**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809038/how-can-i-manually-fire-an-event-that-i-wired-up-using-jquery

when you .click() then use .PreventDefault()

Comment: Did you try live() jquery function? http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In IE, you can call `.click()` on the element, but for standard browsers you need to simulate the click event by creating a native mouse event and then use `dispatchEvent` to trigger it.

I summed it all up in this jQuery 'plugin':

```
$.fn.simulateClick = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        if('createEvent' in document) {
            var doc = this.ownerDocument,
                evt = doc.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, doc.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } else {
            this.click(); // IE
        }
    });
}
```

Now, just call:

```
$('.edithost').simulateClick();
```

Comment: +1 from me. I'm deleting my answer, as it is basically the same thing.

Comment: I have improved it (I hope) to this:
` $.fn.simulateClick = function () {
  if ('createEvent' in document) {
   var doc = document;
   var evt = doc.createEvent('MouseEvents');
   evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, doc.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
   return this.each(function () {
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
   });
  }
  else
   return this.each(function () {
    this.click(); // IE
   });
 };`

Answer (score 2):

Try `a[0].click();`

This will execute the `click` method of the DOM element instead of triggering the event.

Comment: Works great in Firefox, do you happen to know if it's properly supported in other browsers?

Comment: This does not work in WebKit, you need to manually create the event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very simple:

```
$('#YourSelector').click();
```

this will emulate a user click.

Comment: It will just trigger listeners bound to click event (if any) - it won't redirect the user, unless one of the listeners does - and that is different from a mouse click

Comment: Yes, you are right :). From the explanation given I went from the assumption that his functions had those listeners.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really get what you want to do.
with this :

```
a.click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can stop the default behaviour of the event (in this case, redirecting to a.attr('href')).
You can then perform whatever task you want and then redirect the user manually.

Is this what you're looking for ?

If you want to trigger the click event, just do

```
a.click();
```

Comment: `click` won't trigger the native click event.