# How to de-select a button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a button that a user is supposed to click to upload files:

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var button = document.getElementById("button"),
    fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
    fileList = document.getElementById("fileList");

button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);

function handleFiles(files) {
  if (!files.length) {
    fileList.innerHTML = "<p>No files selected!</p>";
  } else {
    fileList.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var videoFile = document.createElement("video");
      videoFile.setAttribute("id", "recording");
      videoFile.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
      videoFile.height = 240;
      videoFile.width = 320;
      videoFile.setAttribute("controls", true);
      videoFile.onload = function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
      }
      fileList.appendChild(videoFile);
    }
  }
}
```

Then the user is supposed to use the space bar to pause/play a video. My problem is after the user clicks the button, the button stays clicked so when he or she pushes the space bar, the button is liked again. To solve this problem, the user would have to click somewhere else on the screen (except for the button) and then the space bar will work to pause/play the video. But I do not want the user to click somewhere else. So I tried to click a span element using JS but it did not work:

```
document.getElementById("spanElement").click();
```

This click is supposed to simulate the click the user would on the screen, but it doesn't work because when the spacebar is pressed, the button is clicked.

Any suggestions to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294728/how-do-i-simulate-user-clicking-a-link-in-jquery    .... Looks like something that might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `HTMLElement.blur()` should have the desired effect.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur

```
button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.blur();
}, false);
```

This will remove focus from the element once clicked.

Answer (score 0):

That happen because after the click on the button it still focused, so to solve that behavior you could use **[`.blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur)** in the end of click event.

> The **blur()** method is used to removes keyboard focus from the current element.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (fileElem) {
      fileElem.click();
    }

    e.target.blur(); //Remove focus after click
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add css to the button - pointer events

to disable button: $("#buttonId").css("pointer-events", "none");

to reactivate button: $("#buttonId").css("pointer-events", "auto");