# Auto click div button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I can't get jquery to programatically click this button:

```
<div class="cta bt-add-to-cart" data-prid="90859" role="button" data-error="Per procedere devi selezionare la taglia!">
    <div>Aggiungi al carrello</div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
$('.cta bt-add-to-cart').click();
```

or this:

`$('.cta bt-add-to-cart').trigger('click');`

Comment: Does it work when you click the element manually?

Comment: jquery .click() is a shorthand of .on('click', function) method and trigger doesn't simulate a real click, only fires the handlers defined by you. You can use a click() handler to submit and then trigger it, or you could check the approach on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8295063/2730902

Comment: for those who want to see.. this is the button [link](https://www.graffitishop.it/Sneakers-Streetwear?jsvpd-90859)

Comment: Paraphrased text. Hopefully got the meaning right.

Comment: @LordNeo Not quite. [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click), when called with no arguments, is not a shortcut to `on('click')`, and triggers any event handlers on the element, including form submission if it's a submit button. For instance, clicking on the "Don't Click Me!" button in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyg0zz5x/1/) alerts twice, even though the alert is defined in an `onclick` inline event handler, as is the submit handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify what function to execute when the click takes place. Neither of your attempts do that.

Also, the JQuery selector needs no space between the class names otherwise it will be looking for elements that have the class `bt-add-to-cart` that are descendants of elements that have the class `cta`.

Here's an example:

```js
function theCallbackFunction(){
  // This is where the code to execute lives
  alert("You clicked me!");
}

// This sets up the function as the click event handler for the element
$('.cta.bt-add-to-cart').on("click", theCallbackFunction);

// And this is a way to simulate the user clicking the element
$('.cta.bt-add-to-cart').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cta bt-add-to-cart" data-prid="90859" 
     role="button" data-error="Per procedere devi selezionare la taglia!">
  <div>Aggiungi al carrello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector does not select the button with the HTML you posted - it should be the following:

```
$('.cta.bt-add-to-cart').trigger('click');
```

This should select the element which has both `cta` and `bt-add-to-cart` classes, and trigger any on click events bound to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$('.bt-add-to-cart').click()`, `$('.cta bt-add-to-cart')` returning an empty array like object, if you want to combine two classed then you could do this `$('.cta.bt-add-to-cart')`